# Adding JQuery rule for dynamically added select options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I have two drop down lists, City and Country. City drop down list is filled dynamically based on the Country drop down list selection. So I am trying to validate City drop down list to ensure that a City in selected.

Below is the appendCity function which I use to append items to the City drop down list. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work, so can someone please check it and tell me what I am missing here? and how to fix it?

```
function appendCity(id,cityName){
    $('#city').append("<option id='"+id+"'>" + cityName + "</option>");           
}
```

JS code responsible for appending data to City drop down list:

```
    function loadCities(citiesLst){
        clearCities();
        var arr=citiesLst.split(",");
        for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
            var cityArr=arr[i].split("#");
            appendCity(cityArr[0],cityArr[1]);
        }

        $('#city').rules("add", { required:true, min:1 });
    }

    function clearCities(){
        $('#city').find('option').remove();
    }

    function appendCity(id,cityName){
        $('#city').append("<option id='"+id+"'>" + cityName + "</option>");
    }
```

HTML:

```
  <select id ="country" name="country" onchange="loadCities()">
    <option  value="0" selected="selected">--select--</option>
      <c:forEach var="countrylst" items="${countriesList}">
        <option  value="${countrylst.id}">${countrylst.countryName}</option>
      </c:forEach>
  </select>             

  <select id="city" name="city">
    <option  value="0" selected="selected">--select--</option>
  </select>
```

Answer (score -1):

change

```
$('#city option[id='+id+']').rules("add", { required:true, min:1 });
```

to

```
$('#city').rules("add", { required:true, min:1 });
```

and take it out of the function

**EDIT**

Add validation rule after the loop in `loadCities` function

```
function loadCities(citiesLst){
    clearCities();
    var arr=citiesLst.split(",");
    for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
        var cityArr=arr[i].split("#");
        appendCity(cityArr[0],cityArr[1]);
    }
    // HERE
    $('#city').rules("add", { required:true, min:1 });
}
```

Comment: where shall I place it then? If I place it under document.ready it will not work, so where else I can place it?

Comment: yes in `document.ready` .. with your code it seems like `#city` already been added before dom

Comment: are you calling `appendCity` in loop?

Comment: The city drop down list is not filled when document is ready, instead it is ONLY filled when the visitors select a Country from the Country drop down list in the same form

Comment: @MChan - you know only those tags that are already added will affected by `.rules` so you should run the `.rules` after all options appended

Comment: @imsiso if I have no problem adding .rules after all options are appended, but when I add it under document.ready nothing happens...any thoughts where else I can add it?

Comment: @imsiso which part of code you wish to see so that I can post it? I really don't want to just paste irrelevant code for example like a Java controller code that has nothing to do with validation (even though it is part of the form operation). So if you can be more specific I can post related code

Comment: full parts related to adding options to city select.

Comment: @zzlalani question updated with the append cities code, as well as html code for city / country drop down lists

Comment: @zzlalani I didn't do anything in my code except adding $('#city').rules("add", { required:true, min:1 }); exactly as you have shown in your answer inside the loadCities function...that's all I did, I will update the question with the changes I did